# C# System.InvalidOperationException error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wanted to make a password generator and it should save the password for what you want to use the password  then I wanted that the program displays all the datas in my database. so, I can look at it. Also, I am using Console Application(.NET Framwork).When I used the program without displaying the data, it worked. But, when I put my displaying code, it makes that error.

> System.InvalidOperationException Connection must be valid and open.

I don't know how to fix that. It would be super cool, if you guys can help me and make me more smart :D Here is the program code:

```
string verbindungsdaten = "SERVER = localhost;" +
                          "DATABASE = db;" +
                          "UID = Sarper;" +
                          "PASSWORD = Bmw03082009;";

MySqlConnection verbindung = new MySqlConnection(verbindungsdaten);

Random meinrandom = new Random();
int zahl = meinrandom.Next(100000, 1000000);
Console.WriteLine("Ihr Passwort ist zwischen den Werten: 100000 - 1000000");
Console.Write("Geben sie bitte die Benutzung vom Passwort damit sie es 
wiederverwenden können ein: ");
string benutzung1 = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Ihr Passwort wurde generiert: " + zahl);
Console.WriteLine("Alle Daten im überblick mit Benutzung: ");

string command = "INSERT INTO passwörter VALUES ('" + benutzung1 + "', '" + zahl + "');";

MySqlCommand ausführen = new MySqlCommand(command);
ausführen.Connection = verbindung;

string com = "SELECT * FROM passwörter;";
MySqlCommand com11 = new MySqlCommand(com);

verbindung.Open();
ausführen.ExecuteNonQuery();
MySqlDataReader Reader;
    
Reader = com11.ExecuteReader();
Reader.Read();
Console.WriteLine("Benutzung " + Reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Passwort " + Reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
verbindung.Close();
```

It is german again because I am from Germany.That are only things in the WriteLine codes, but I think you can unserstand it.  :D

Comment: The problem is poping up in the Reader = com11.ExecuteReader(); code

Comment: Side note, don't store plain text passwords, use command parameters to prevent SQLi attacks, use `usings` statements to ensure objects are disposed. If that's the real password to your server, change it and get a new one, never post this information. There's other issues here as well, TBH, rethink your approach and start fresh focusing on one issue at a time.

Comment: Sorry but what is a parameter ? I am new at programming

Comment: Hmm ok i will try

Comment: @zaggler and you :D you are helping everytime to my questions last time also :D thank you also

Comment: You're welcome, take one thing at a time. Please also reference your other question where I left comments as well.

Comment: One more question to you zaggler so i think you know that i am from germany and i want to say that i am not grown up so much so i want to say i am kid :D i think you will think i am dumb or something else but what is a hashing or using paramaters it will be very nice when you can say me the answer :D

Comment: Not at all, we all are learning. Check out [hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in that article to get an understanding of the intention [or](https://medium.com/@mehanix/lets-talk-security-salted-password-hashing-in-c-5460be5c3aae) and or [this](https://www.simongilbert.net/hashing-passwords-md5-bcrypt-pbkdf2-csharp-dotnetcore/) may be useful.

Comment: `new MySqlCommand(..., verbindung);` or `verbindung.CreateCommand(...);`

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you never assigned a connection to com11

Comment: @Omar De La Rossa thank you! I forgotten to assign a connection to com11 :D next time i will better analize my code